# How to do a specific completion action without adding some unnecessary comment ?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I have the following warning

> The serializable class myClassD4 does not declare a static final
>   serialVersionUID field of type long

From this interesting discussion https://stackoverflow.com/a/285809/813853 I know what to do to handle this warning.

**BUT** my problem is kind of different, it is related to Eclipse parametrization. When I get this warning, I do right click. And choose completion action :

> Add generated serial version id

the problem is that this add a comment block , something like /* ** */. That I don't want. Please, how to get rid of that ? I have looked on the configuration of Eclipse but not found it YET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it :)

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments -> Fields

All I have to do is to edit the default string.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know is to turn off comment-generation for ALL fields (=instance vairables).  This is how to do it:
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Template .
Open Comments tab, click on Fields, click on Edit button and remove the text